# Changing variables from outside

Tags: c

In `main()` function I initialize a couple of variables (`int` and `int*` array). Then I print something out and read them from the console `scanf`.

I want to place this functionality into some external function so that the main will look like this:

```
int main()
{
    int n = 0, x = 0;
    int *arr = NULL;    
    load(&n, &x, &arr);
}
```

After `load()` function call I want the variables to be exactly as they were set inside of the `load()` function. How can I do this?

And second question, just out of curiosity:

```
/**
 * Description of the function
 *
 * @param int n Foo
 * @param int x Bar
 * @param int *arr Does something
 */
void load(int n, int x, int *arr)
{
    // something
}
```

Is this documentation useful in C coding, and is it a good practice?

Comment: Check this explanation about [call-by-reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call-by-reference#Call_by_reference)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing address of two int and one pointer(third argument), you should receive   first  two arguments in pointer(one `*`) to int and third argument in pointer to pointer(two `**`) of int:

```
void load(int* n, int* x, int **arr){
//           ^       ^ one*     ^ two **
    *n = 10;
    *x = 9;
}
```

In load function you can assign values to `*n` and `*x` because both points to valid memory addresses  but you **can't do `**arr = 10`** simply because `arr` doesn't points to any memory (*points to NULL*) so first you have to first allocate memory for `*arr`, do like:

```
void load(int* n, int* x, int **arr){
    *n = 10;
    *x = 9;
    *arr = malloc(sizeof(int));
    **arr = 10;
}
```

> **Is this documentation useful in C coding, and is it a good practice?**

Yes

but Sometimes I documents my function arguments  like in following ways:

```
void load(int n,     // is  a Foo
         int x,      // is a  Bar
         int **arr){ // do some thing 
    // something
}
```

A reference: [for document practice](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/40666/help-finding-good-documentation-for-c-c)

**Edit** As you are commenting, do like below I am writing, it will not give any error/because of `malloc()`.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void load(int* n, int* x, int **arr){
    *n = 10;
    *x = 9;
    *arr = malloc(sizeof(int));
    **arr = 10;
    printf("\n Enter Three numbers: ");
    scanf("%d%d%d",n,x,*arr);
}
int main(){
    int n = 0, x = 0;
    int *arr = NULL;    
    load(&n, &x, &arr);
    printf("%d %d %d\n", n, x, *arr);
    free(arr);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Compile and run like:

```
~$ gcc ss.c -Wall
:~$ ./a.out 

 Enter Three numbers: 12 13 -3
12 13 -3
```

As Commented by OP:

> "Invalid convertion from void* to int*" when I change this to *arr = malloc(sizeof(int)*(*n));

[syntax of malloc():](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_is_SYNTAX_of_malloc_and_calloc_in_C_language)

```
void *malloc(size_t size);
```

malloc() returns `void*` and `*arr` type is `int*` that is the reason compiler messages because of different types : `"Invalid convertion from void* to int*"`

But I avoid casting when malloc(), since: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858) (*read Unwind's answer*)

Comment: Why does *arr = malloc(sizeof(int)*n) doesn't work ? (Invalid operand of types)

Comment: @user2251921 are you declare like `int **arr` ? previously I made mistake.

Comment: Yes, it says "Invalid convertion from void* to int*" when I change this to *arr = malloc(sizeof(int)*(*n));

Comment: @user2251921 Implicit conversion from `void*` to `int*` is legal in C but would need a cast (`static_cast`) in C++.